# MVC4 and resources from another project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, resources

How can I use resource file from another ASP.NET MVC 4 project, please?
Unfortunately, the Web project doesn't see the Resource project.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

```
Solution 'Example'
  +Example.Resources
   +Resources.en.resx
   +Resources.resx
  +Example.Web
  ...
```

I have added the reference of Example.Resources to the Web project, but I can't use the resources because it doesn't see it:

using Example.Resources doesn't exist in the Web project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create one class library project and add the resource file in that project.
And add the reference your class library project to whenever you want so it will able to use this resource file in your target project.

```
Like Syntax :-  ViewBag.IsUpdate = SurveyTool_Resources.GeneralResources.LUpdate;
```

**GeneralResources is resource file name and SurveyTool_Resources is resource project name.
.**

**Check Below Image.**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have created my resource class library project and have added to my web project but it didn't see it. Solution name: Example, resource project name Example.Resource, web project name: Example.Web. I try to use resource: Example.Resource but it doesn't see .Resource. Can it be due to the solution and projects name?

Comment: Yes you need to change the Resource file name “Resources” to something else because it is conflict Resources module of .net.

Comment: Thank you, but the VS did not generate the code for the resource file.

Comment: Please explain your problem in detail.